# State is undefined when state variables used in functions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a variable in state that I'm updating via a websocket. When logging the variable to check its state it has updated correctly, but when I reference it in a function for use, it is undefined. I'm new to React and state and not sure what I'm doing wrong.

On both lines where I use `${contactCalling}` it shows as undefined.

Any help much appreciated!

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import CallPane from './CallPane'
import '@opentok/client';

import {
    SERVER_BASE_URL,
} from './config';


const BASEURL = 'http://localhost:4001'
const socket = socketIOClient(BASEURL);

function App() {
    const [callFlag, setCallFlag] = useState(Boolean)
    const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([])
    const [contactCalling, setContactCalling] = useState('')

    console.log(contactCalling)

    socket.on("outgoing data", data => {
        console.log(data);
        setContactCalling(data.caller)
        alert(`${contactCalling} is calling you`)
        console.log('Call answered')
        setCallFlag(true);
    });

    useEffect ((contactCalling) => {
        fetch(SERVER_BASE_URL + `/room/${contactCalling}`)
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => setApiData(data))
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error('Failed to get session credentials', err);
                alert('Failed to get opentok sessionId and token. Make sure you have updated the config.js file.');
            });
    },[])

    if (callFlag) {
        return (
            <div className="CallPane">
                <CallPane credentials={apiData}/>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="CallPane">
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: start with normal, full class react components, lifecycles, etc.

Comment: yeah I agree with @xadm. If you're new to reactjs, start with class components. react-hooks is already close to advance category.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting out with a class based component rather than a functional one

create a constructor with a state object inside of it

and use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle to fetch the data from the socket and save it to the state using `setState` function once the component mounts properly

the `componentDidMount` lifecycle will re-render the DOM so it will look like it is the initial render. If the fetching is slow, you will see it blank for a moment and then renders to what you need it to be (it renders it twice: one time before fetching the data and one when fetching the data is completed so keep that in mind you can find more about lifecycles here https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

you can use Redux to do the fetching from the websocket and save it to the redux store then update your component with it

hope my answer helped a bit

Answer (score 0):

For your first setContactCalling call, setContactCalling is an asynchronous function. Calling it right after like that won't guarantee that the value has been changed (as a matter of fact it most likely hasn't been changed yet). You can rely on react to render the component again, however, once the state has changed. Instead of alerting, just use the values in the component. Maybe use a modal instead.

For the second call inside of useEffect, you're attempting to pass contactCalling into the function...however that value is undefined because useEffect won't pass anything into it. So it will log out as undefined. The value contactCalling will be set via setContactCalling outside of the useEffect callback. Instead of passing it in like you're doing, simply add it to the array of values for useEffect to watch like so:

```
useEffect (() => {
    fetch(SERVER_BASE_URL + `/room/${contactCalling}`)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => setApiData(data))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error('Failed to get session credentials', err);
            alert('Failed to get opentok sessionId and token. Make sure you have updated the config.js file.');
        });
},[contactCalling])
```